# Problem trying to build my own sklean transformer

Tags: scikit-learn, transformer

I build the following sklearn transformer :

```
class Cat2Rat( BaseEstimator , TransformerMixin ) :
   def __init__( self , col2trans ) :
      self._col2trans = col2trans

   def fit( self, X, y = None ):
      return self 

   def transform( self , X , y = None ) :
      for col in self._col2trans : 
         p = X[ col ].value_counts() / X.shape[0]
         dic = dict( [ ( i , p[i] ) for i in ( X[ col ].value_counts() ).index ] )
         X.replace( { col : dic } , inplace = True )
      return X
```

This transformer is replacing catagorical values by their rates.

For example :

```
myarray = np.array([ [ 1 , 1 , 3 , 'v' , 0 ] , 
                 [ 2 , 2 , 2 , 'v' , 1 ] ,
                 [ 4 , 5 , 1 , 'w' , 1 ] ,
                 [ 2 , 1 , 9 , 'w' , 1 ] , 
                 [ 1 , 0 , 4 , 'w' , 1 ] ] )

colnames = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' , 'four' , 'target' ]

df = pd.DataFrame( myarray , columns = colnames )
```

Value 'v' ( 'w' ) for column 'four' is replaced by 2/5 ( 3/5 ).

My purpose is to fit the transformer on df and apply it to another dataframe df2 :

```
myarray2 = np.array([ [ 2 , 7 , 3 , 'v' , 0 ] , 
                    [ 9 , 2 , 2 , 'v' , 0 ] ,
                    [ 4 , 5 , 1 , 'w' , 1 ] ]  )

colnames2 = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' , 'four' , 'target' ]

df2 = pd.DataFrame( myarray2 , columns = colnames2 )
```

I am doing this that way :

```
# Transformer instance
trsf = Cat2Rat( [ 'four' ] )

# Fitting
trsf.fit( df )

# Then applying
trsf.transform( df2 )
```

But the rates are those of column 'four' values of df2 not df ( on which the transformer was fitted ).

I must have been missing something on the way to properly build such a transformer.

Could someone give some clue on how to fix the transformer so that it gives proper result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `dic` should happen inside the `fit` method; you're wanting the rates to be based on the dataframe passed to `fit`.  So you'll want to set `dic` as another class attribute, to be referenced in the `transform` method.

(This kind of replacement is called *target encoding*, and there's [an existing package](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/categorical-encoding/targetencoder.html) to do it in sklearn.)

Answer (score 0):

Considering Ben Reiniger's answer I've made some change in my sklearn transformer :

```
class Cat2Rat( BaseEstimator , TransformerMixin ) :
   def __init__( self , col2trans ) :
       self._col2trans = col2trans


   def fit( self , X , y = None ):
       self._dic_col_p = {}

       for col in self._col2trans :
           p = X[ col ].value_counts() / X.shape[0]
           dic = dict( [ ( i , p[i] ) for i in ( X[ col ].value_counts() ).index ] )
           self._dic_col_p.update( { col : dic } )

       return self


   def transform( self , X , y = None ) :

       for col , dic_p in self._dic_col_p.items() : 
           X.replace( { col : dic_p } , inplace = True )
       return X
```

The fit method now produce a dictionary with keys containing columns names and values containing the proportion of each columns value.

For example, self._dic_col_p contains after fitting :

```
{ 'four' : {'w': 0.6, 'v': 0.4} , 'five' : {'c': 0.4, 'b': 0.4, 'a': 0.2} }
```

where :

```
myarray = np.array([ [ 1 , 1 , 3 , 'v' , 'a' , 0 ] , 
                   [ 2 , 2 , 2 , 'v' , 'b' , 1 ] ,
                   [ 4 , 5 , 1 , 'w' , 'c' , 1 ] ,
                   [ 2 , 1 , 9 , 'w' , 'c' , 1 ] , 
                   [ 1 , 0 , 4 , 'w' , 'b' , 1 ] ] )

colnames = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' , 'four' , 'five' , 'target' ]

df = pd.DataFrame( myarray , columns = colnames )
```

Thks.